# Why is my lock screen scrambled sometimes?

Tags: 4.0-ice-cream-sandwich, lock-screens, samsung

Occasionally my phone (specs below) will awake to the dots on the lock screen being all the way up in the corner. I can't unlock it because the other 6 dots are cut off and turning the phone or sleep/awaking it doesn't change the layout. My only option, annoyingly, is to restart.

Here's an image of it doing it this morning:

[image: Screenshot]
<sup>Screenshot (click for larger variant)</sup>

The white chunk is an ICE number I've hidden. How do I stop this?

My phone is:

- A Samsung Galaxy S2X SGH-T989D on Koodo
- Running Android version 4.0.4
- Kernel Version 3.0.8-perf-T989DTLLG2-CL836160 se.infra@SEP-89#1 SMP PREEMPT Fri Jul 13 23:39:44 KST 2012
- Build Number IMM76D.TLLG2
- Using a stock lock screen

Thanks for any assistance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After enough frustration with this issue I actually moved to a custom ROM. This mainly happens due to rotation as mentioned by [Colin](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/63467/6204)

I used to face this issue when I had the phone in landscape mode, in an app and then locked the phone! When it came back on there was major juggling and it used to end up this way!

Software Fix:

1. Pray that samsung fixes it! or
2. Get a custom rom!

Temporary fix:
1) Dont lock your phone without exiting an app in landscape mode

Sorry but this was what I used to do, given S2 is a pretty old phone I highly doubt an official fix for it.

Answer (score 2):

My best guess would be an issue that is causing part of the render process of slide lock to take place in landscape mode. I have no idea why that would happen although I have had some strange screen rotation issues with my nexus 7 and a factory reset did indeed fix it.

But since you don't want to turn to that here are some suggestions:

-Try locking rotation on your phone (unlocking when needed)

-Switch your lock screen to PIN or password (there error could be isolated to the slide password).

-Upgrade to a new version of android using kies (it should be available)

Let me know if any of those work out

Comment: Even PIN lock has this issue, locking the rotation is a good fix though :)

Answer (score -3):

Factory reset is the only solution. At the very least it will exclude software issues.

Comment: To check that out, one also could boot into [safe-mode](http://android.stackexchange.com/tags/safe-mode/info) first (without losing any data).

Comment: This occurs way too infrequently to consider nuking everything for, and doesn't explain how I can avoid this from happening in the future